# how to display names who's initial are starting from K,B,A in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to display names who's initial are  starting from K,B,A in sql? The result should comes like eg:-Keven,karun,Bean,Brown,Aron,Abiel

Comment: hi guys thanks for your answers, as I mentioned in the question, I want the output in a different order i.e names starting from K should display first, then B and last should be starting from A,  according to your queries the output comes in ascending order, which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select name_field
From yourTable
Where upper( substr( name_field, 1, 1)) in ('K', 'B', 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [REGEXP_LIKE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/regexp_like.php) as shown below. It can match a regular expression, which is a better alternative in this case instead of using multiple `like` statements.

<kbd>**[`DBFiddle Demo`](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=88bfc4c4d25951ee21034e0d58998193)**</kbd>

```
select name from 
your_table t
where REGEXP_LIKE (name, '^[K|B|A]','i');
```

Regex `^[K|B|A]` matches every word which starts with either `K or B or A`. `i` for case insensitive matching.

Comment: Because you are in a single character expression you don't need the pipe characters to represent OR. It's implicit, in fact the pipe has become an alternative starting character for the name. So use `^[KBA]` as the regex. Remember that REGEXP can be succinct but has a CPU penalty for very large number of executions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [REGEX_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm) to perform this operation.

What it does is it performs a regular expression matching instead of a simple pattern matching.

Comment: I want the names according to this pattern only K, B, A, all names which are starting from k should be displayed first then after B And then A. if the names who starts from A those names should be displayed last as I want the name series in the form of K, B, A

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT name FROM users WHERE name LIKE 'k%' OR name LIKE 'b%' OR name LIKE 'a%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci`

`%` matches any string, so the above query will match any name starting with b, a or k. the COLLATE rule is there to tell the query that it is case insensitive.

Comment: You could also write this as `LIKE ANY ('K%', 'B%', 'A%') `

Comment: Aha, thanks for the heads up ! I knew there had to be a way to do it faster.